# Translating 'where' condition from SAS to R

Tags: r, sorting, sas, where-clause, language-translation

I have a SAS macro that I need to convert to R and since I am new to SAS I am having a little trouble understanding one part of the code.

At the beginning of the macro, I have this line that defines the macro -

```
%MACRO macroname(sdate=01JAN2011,edate=01JAN2013, FILTERS=platform in (1,2,3),OUT=data_final)

%if %length(&filters) > 2 %then %let filters = and &filters; 
%else %let filters = %str( );
```

In one of the stages in the macro, I have the following command -

```
proc sort data = A noduplicates;
  where 1 &filters;
  by id, date;
  run;
```

I understand that in the where condition, the filter conditions will be applied. But what does the 1 do? similarly, what does the if else condition on the filter column do?

Thanks!

Comment: You should know that the best way to test your code and help you to find a solution is to create a data sample (a reproducible example). Generally it is half the way to solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can also be written as 1=1, and is essentially a static TRUE condition.

This is actually a neat little trick that gets around the problem of adding multiple where clauses (as macro variables).  Each where condition must be separated by an operator (AND / OR, usually AND), but it is not always known if another condition *precedes* the one you are adding.  For instance, you may want the flexibility to add the same `&filter` to both of these where claueses:

```
where x=1 &filter;

where &filter;
```

of course the first example must resolve to `x=1 AND some=filter;` and the second must **not** resolve to `where AND some=filter;`

Remember, any condition in a where clause ultimately resolves to true or false.  By adding "1", we have a static "TRUE" condition that has no effect on the query but does give us flexibility (and readability) in the code (basically avoids more macro *%if %else* statements) if we *always* prepend the "AND" to &filter.

```
where 1 &filter
```

instead of

```
where %if %length(&filter)>4 and "%substr(%upcase(&filter))" ne AND %then %do;
   where 1 and &filter
%end;
%else %do;
   where &filter
%end;
```

Comment: Well! ok for the "1" ( obvisouly TRUE where clause ) but what about this line `"%if %length(&filters) > 2 %then %let filters = and &filters;"` looks like a recursive call? Does the code test that it has a valid condition? I am learning sas too so sorry for my obvious question.

Comment: @agstudy remember that macros are basically just text processing. `%let filters = ___` means set the value of the `filters` macro to the value on the LHS of the equals sign. Here's it's the equivalent of `filters <- paste("and", filters)` in R.

Comment: @agstudy - the value of &filters on the right will resolve BEFORE the new value of %let filters= is set.  So it will contain the previous value of itself, but there is no implied loop (the code just gets scanned then rescanned until all variables that can be resolved, are resolved)

Comment: @RawFocus +1! thanks. it is really text processing. I think what make me confused is the upcase argument FILTERS. I forget that sas ignore case.